# Unable to install subeclipse plugin in juno with worklight 6.0.0.2014 plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have eclipse 4.2.0(64-bit) with Worklight 6.0.0.2014 plugin. Now I am trying to install subeclipse plugin from eclipse marketplace and getting the below error message:

"`Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software currently installed: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201412160436 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201412160436)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (epp.package.jee 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.1.201.v201203071941 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.1.201.v201203071941)
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.3.0.v20130510_1037 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.3.0.v20130510_1037)
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.1.202.v201208171701 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.1.202.v201208171701)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Dojo Mobile Application Tools 6.0.0.201412160435 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201412160435)
    To: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core [6.0.0.201412160435]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201412160436 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201412160436)
    To: com.ibm.imp.dojo.feature.feature.group 6.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Core 6.0.0.201412160435 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core 6.0.0.201412160435)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.3.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (epp.package.jee 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.2.20130211-1820]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JavaScript Development Tools 1.4.0.v201111090639-7H7DFeHFC7sRemSZgYbe4 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.v201111090639-7H7DFeHFC7sRemSZgYbe4)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.1.201.v201203071941]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JavaScript Development Tools 1.4.1.v201208171701-7H7DFg0FC7sReqSyfqesWi (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.v201208171701-7H7DFg0FC7sReqSyfqesWi)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.1.202.v201208171701]`"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing the installation flow helps resolving such issues.
Try to first install the subeclipse plug-in followed by installing the Worklight plug-in.

If the problem persists, and you are an IBM customer or Business Partner, you can open a PMR (IBM support ticket) to see if it is possible to resolve this issue.

Comment: I tried installing subeclipse first and then worklight studio, now I am getting problem for installing worklight studio.

Comment: Then this is not a supported path... Feel free to open a PMR.

Comment: Using 32-bit eclipse we can install both the plugins